# TypeError: first argument must be callable or None - error is not coming first time but coming later

Tags: python

I am having this line to create a defaultdict and initialize it with a list as a value.

```
page_by_due_date = defaultdict(list)
due_pages_list = []

for page, page_summary_dict in summary_by_page.items():
    scheduled_due_date = page_summary_dict.get('8.scheduled_due_date')
    page_by_due_date[str(scheduled_due_date)].append(page)
    if scheduled_due_date <= datetime.date.today():
        due_pages_list.append(page)

print(sorted(due_pages_list))
pprint.pprint(page_by_due_date)
```

When I run this code first time, it works properly. But if I rerun this code, I get this error. I do not know why it is considering 'list' as not callable. I am using Jupyter notebook - if I restart kernel and run the code again, it works.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-56b08ad56f3e> in <module>
    ----> 1 page_by_due_date = defaultdict(list)
          2 due_pages_list = []
          3 
          4 for page, page_summary_dict in summary_by_page.items():
          5     scheduled_due_date = page_summary_dict.get('8.scheduled_due_date')

    TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Please note that I have done a google search and read through these 2 posts already and they do not answer my question:

[TypeError: first argument must be callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422670/typeerror-first-argument-must-be-callable?rq=1)

[defaultdict : first argument must be callable or None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137849/defaultdict-first-argument-must-be-callable-or-none)

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry for missing the full code - I updated the question to add the function.

Comment: So far I suspect that you overwrite `list` somewhere else.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, that is what I was searching and now I have found it - thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the clue from @KlausD, I reviewed the code after and found an instance where I am using the variable name 'list' which would have overwritten this. Found the issue and fixed it. Thank you for the help

Comment: I dont have variable named list, but first time my code run correctly. After first run, it gives above said error, Type Error

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan please search for the word 'list' in the source file where you get TypeError and you might find the culprit. If you need help, can you please post the relevant portions of the code, may be in a separate question and link it here.